# Is there a way to have shared control tmux session?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, tmux

I'm looking for something similar to the `screen -x` of gnu screen for Linux

Answer (score 8):

You can attach to tmux sessions owned by different users by giving the correct permissions and doing the following:

Host

```
tmux -S /tmp/team
```

Client

```
tmux -S /tmp/team attach
```

For example, to set the permissions for all users:

> chmod 777 /tmp/team

Comment: `chmod 777`: nonononono! Never ever run `chmod 777`. It is practically never required! Not even for "testing purposes". If the file is readable, then it's readable. If it's writable by the `user` or `group` that need to write to it, then it's writable. There is absolutely zero need to give everyone write permissions, and forgetting to `chmod` it back to something sane is exactly how multinationals get hacked. Just don't do it. Ever. I wrote [an introduction of Unix permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35895436/660921). Please read it!

Comment: In this case, just put the users in the same group and `chgrp` it to that.

Comment: Just for clarity sake, this answer is _not_ the same as "screen -x", which allows users to have separate control of each buffer/window, while tmux only lets one user control each session at a time.

Answer (score 4):

It will work for you by simply attaching the same session, with no special switch.

One of the cool advantages of tmux for shared sessions is that it automatically adjusts the pane sizes to the smallest actual terminal size of all of the currently connected clients.

Comment: I.e. just run `tmux attach`, or `tmux attach -t 4` to attach to session 4, etc.

Comment: just beware that you can't share tmux session between different users